# I have two sets of pdf from different folders that i went to join as one based on the same name and output in the same folder of first pdf group

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

I have two folder directory

```
directory1<-"C:/Folder1/"
directory2<-"C:/Folder2/"
```

Folder 1 contains file

```
"123456.pdf", "234567.pdf", "345678.pdf", "456789.pdf"
```

Folder 2 contains file

```
"123456_Jon.pdf","234567_Mike.pdf", "345678_Bill.pdf","456789_Ralph.pdf","Random_file.pdf"
```

If the pdf's in folder 1 and 2 share the first 6  numbers then i want to join them and create a new file in `directory1` named

```
"123456_Join.pdf","234567_Join.pdf","345678_Join.pdf","456789_Join.pdf"
```

Comment: Are the matches unique?

Comment: @MartinGal yes the matches unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your filenames are stored in

```r
files_1 <- c("123456.pdf", "234567.pdf", "345678.pdf", "456789.pdf")
files_2 <- c("123456_Jon.pdf","234567_Mike.pdf", "345678_Bill.pdf","456789_Ralph.pdf","Random_file.pdf")

library(qpdf)

for (file in files_1) {
  ext_num <- sub("(^\\d{6}).*", "\\1", file)
  target  <- grepl(paste0("^", ext_num), files_2)

  if (!any(target)) next
  
  pdf_combine(c(file, file.path(directory2, files_2[target])),
              output = paste(directory1, ext_num, "Join.pdf", sep = "_"))
  
}
```

should give you your desired output.

Comment: I got a message that said `Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path),wislash,mustwork): path[1]- "123456 text_value.pdf": The system cannot find the file specificed`

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this error. I added a handling, if the file from `files_1` doesn't have a match in `files_2`. Perhaps this solves the problem.

Comment: I still get the same error. The first 6 characters of each pdf match though they are formatted differently. Is it cause of the underscore? I forgot to add there is a blank between the first 6 number characters and the name. Though i don't think that would make a difference.

Comment: Is directory 2 not referenced?

Comment: I got False for target but i'll try to add files_ <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "^.pdf"

Comment: `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\."` This worked `list.files(path = directory, pattern = "\\pdf$")`

Comment: I get this error message now with `Error: unexpected ')' in "  output = paste(directory1, ext_num, "Join.pdf", sep = ""))"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Comment: It's nearly impossible to debug your code without seeing it.

Comment: Perhaps the `pdf_combine()` syntax is flawed. I can't check it nomw.

Comment: It worked. The issue was the brackets at the end `pdf_combine(input= c(file, file.path(directory2, files_2[target])),
  output = paste(directory, ext_num, "Join.pdf", sep = "_"))`. You had three after `files_2[target] it should be two. Thank you so much and my apologies.

Comment: My apologies for this stupid error. I couldn't test the code since I'm mobile atm. Didn't think of a bracket error...